# Sobrescritura de objetos en Python

Tags: python, poo, diccionarios, herencia

Tengo este problema con objetos de subclases que heredan de una misma superclase y que tienen por atributo un diccionario. Pongo el código y luego hablo sobre el problema

```
class Personal_Universitario:
    datos = {
             "ID" : 0, 
             "Nombre" : "", 
             "Email" : ""}

    def __init__(self, ident, name, email):
        self.datos["ID"] = ident
        self.datos["Nombre"] = name
        self.datos["Email"] = email

class Oficina(Personal_Universitario):
    
    def __init__(self, ident, name, email, job = None):
        self.datos["Puesto"] = job
        super().__init__(ident, name, email)

pu_1 = Personal_Universitario(2004, "Julio Serna", "julioserna@ucm.es") 
print("Referencia en memoria de pu_1")  
print(pu_1)  
print("\nAtributos de pu_1 antes de crear otro objeto")  
print(pu_1.datos)  
of_1 = Oficina(28982, "Clara Montero", "claramontero@ucm.es","Biblioteca")  
print("\nReferencia en memoria de of_1")  
print(of_1)  
print("\nAtributos de of_1")  
print(of_1.datos)  
print("\nReferencia en memoria de pu_1 después de crear otro objeto (sigue siendo la misma)")  
print(pu_1)  
print("\nAtributos de pu_1 después de crear otro objeto (por algún motivo se sobreescriben los del anterior)")  
print(pu_1.datos)
```

Como podéis ver, creo correctamente un objeto con ciertos atributos, pero cuando creo otro objeto, con distinto nombre y de una clase distinta (aunque heredando de la misma, que ahí debe estar el problema), se me sobrescribe en los atributos del anterior.

Me pregunté si de alguna manera el segundo objeto que creo es en realidad una referencia del primero y por eso se me sobreescribe la información, lo cual tendría cierto sentido porque los diccionarios se pasan por referencia y no por valor, pero las direcciones en memoria de ambos objetos son distintas.

El código que tengo que escribir tiene más clases y objetos, esta es la versión más simple posible en la que aparece este problema, e introduciendo más objetos el resultado es que los datos de todos se sustituyen por los del último creado con la excepción de los atributos propios que tenga la clase.

Algo importante a tener en cuenta es que si se hace el mismo código pero sustituyendo el diccionario por variables comunes tal que

```
ID = ""
nombre = ""
email = ""
```

, el problema deja de existir, funciona como debería funcionar y no se sobrescribe la información

Comment: `class Personal_Universitario:

    def __init__(self, ident, name, email):
        self.datos = {"ID": ident, "Nombre": name, "Email": email}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### El problema

Aunque los objetos son diferentes, y parece que cada uno tiene su propio atributo `.datos`, en realidad esos atributos se refieren a un mismo objeto subyacente (el diccionario en cuestión).

Esto puedes verlo fácilmente haciendo uso del operador `is` que compara si dos referencias apuntan en realidad a un mismo objeto:

```
>>> pu_1 is of_1
False             # Son objetos diferentes, hasta aqui bien

>>> pu_1.datos is of_1.datos
True              # Aqui esta el problema, el atributo apunta al mismo dict
```

¿Por qué sucede esto? Pues porque **tú lo has pedido así**. Has declarado `datos` como un **atributo de clase** en lugar de hacerlo como un atributo de instancia. Los atributos de clase son compartidos entre todas las instancias de esa misma clase (y de sus hijas), porque de hecho no existen en las instancias sino que existen solo en la clase.

### Cómo funciona eso

Al escribir atributos en el cuerpo de una clase, fuera de cualquiera de sus métodos, estás creando atributos de clase. Por ejemplo aqui:

```
class Ejemplo:
   dato = 0
```

En este ejemplo `dato` es un atributo de la clase. Es decir, existe aún si no existiera ningún objeto (instancia) de esa clase. Puedes acceder a ese dato usando `Ejemplo.dato`.

Cuando creas un objeto: `ej = Ejemplo()`, ocurre que ahora tienes dos sintaxis a elegir para acceder al atributo de la clase. O bien `Ejemplo.dato` igual que antes de crear el objeto, o bien `ej.dato`. En el segundo caso, aunque accedas a través de un objeto, el atributo en cuestión no forma parte del objeto, por lo que Python lo buscará en la clase y usará el que allí encuentre. Mira:

```
>>> ej1 = Ejemplo()
>>> ej2 = Ejemplo()
>>> ej1 is ej2
False
>>> ej1.dato is ej2.dato
True
>>> ej1.dato is Ejemplo.dato
True
>>> ej1.dato
0
>>> Ejemplo.dato = 100
>>> ej1.dato
100
>>> ej2.dato
100
```

Vemos en el ejemplo anterior algo interesante. Si modificas el **atributo de clase** mediante asignación directa (`Ejemplo.dato = 100`) eso va a causar que aparentemente se haya modificado ese atributo en las instancias, como vemos al imprimir después `ej1.dato` y `ej2.dato`. Lo que ocurre en realidad es que ya que las instancias no tienen ese atributo y Python usa el de clase, obviamente ese vale ahora 100.

**Sin embargo** si hicieras `ej1.dato = 200`, aquí **el comportamiento sería diferente**. La asignación no se está haciendo a través de la clase, sino a través de un objeto. En este caso Python no escribe el 200 en el atributo de la clase, sino que **crea un atributo de objeto** con el mismo nombre, y le da el valor 200.

Es decir, a partir de ese momento el objeto `ej1` tendría un *atributo de objeto* (que vale 200) separado del *atributo de clase* (que vale todavía 100). Ambos tienen el mismo nombre, por lo que a partir de ahi cuando hagas `ej1.dato` te estarás refiriendo al atributo de objeto. Si quieres acceder al atributo de clase debes usar `Ejemplo.dato`. Por su parte el objeto `ej2` sigue sin tener atributo de objeto, por lo que `ej2.dato` seguirá accediendo al atributo de clase y dando el valor 100.

Por eso cuando en tu ejemplo eliminas el diccionario y dejas variables "normales" el problema "desaparece" (porque cada vez que reasignas una con `self.nombre = nombre` por ejemplo, estarás creando un atributo de instancia, separado del atributo de clase).

En cambio cuando usas un diccionario esto no sucede porque en ningún punto de tu código reasignas nada a `self.datos`. Es decir, en ningún lugar haces `self.datos = otra_cosa`. En cambio haces `self.datos[clave] = otra_cosa`, lo que no es una reasignación del atributo `.datos`, sino de una de sus claves. Por tanto se sigue accediendo al atributo de clase para ello.

¿Confuso? Sí. Mucho. Por eso **mejor no usar atributos de clase**.

### La solución

Mejor no uses atributos de clase si no tienes una buena razón para ello.

Algunos programadores novatos (a mi me ha pasado) usan atributos de clase como una forma de estructurar mejor el código, "declarando" en un lugar bien visible las variables de la clase, pensando que estos serán copiados después a los atributos de objeto, pero hemos visto que eso no es así.

Sin usar atributos de clase, la inicialización del diccionario debería ocurrir en el constructor. Tu clase por tanto debería ser así:

```py
class Personal_Universitario:
    def __init__(self, ident, name, email):
        self.datos = {}
        self.datos["ID"] = ident
        self.datos["Nombre"] = name
        self.datos["Email"] = email

class Oficina(Personal_Universitario):
    def __init__(self, ident, name, email, job = None):
        super().__init__(ident, name, email)
        self.datos["Puesto"] = job
```